# Problem with combining std::remove_if + str.erase()

Tags: c++, std

I have a string that must be remove every characters from specified point till whitespace character.

example(`str = "I Have A Nice Day"` specified Point:  Beginning of Nice, what i want is take "Nice" (it can be every word that i don't know the range. must be till the whitespace char) )

I wrote this Code:

```
Mystr = "I Have A Nice Day"
Mystr = SearchingString.substr(9, (SearchingString.size()-9)); // Everything in interval 0-9 must be deleted
Mystr.erase(std::remove_if(Mystr.begin(), myStr.end(), isspace), Mystr.end()); //supposed to erase everything since whitespace character
```

but instead; it only erases whitespace characters. so my output like "NiceDay" instead of "Nice".

What is the problem with my code?

From the answer, I understand that my problem misunderstood. so I'll share excat code:

Data written in .txt file `ID 58 0`
(I get every ID's with getline. 58 Represents person's id. 0 represent it's not crypted. But id can be 324, 3216372173, or more. what i want to seperate id info with crypted info)

code:

```
 while (!Input.eof()) {

            ID = SearchingString.substr(3, (SearchingString.size()-3));
            ID.erase(std::remove_if(ID.begin(), ID.end(), isspace), ID.end());
            isdecrypted = SearchingString.substr((ID.size() + 4), 1);
```

note that: isdecrypted, ID, SearchingString's are string type

I know that adding `ID.erase(ID.end);` before iscrypted,

```
while (!Input.eof()) {
    
                ID = SearchingString.substr(3, (SearchingString.size()-3));
                ID.erase(std::remove_if(ID.begin(), ID.end(), isspace), ID.end()); 
ID.erase(ID.end()); //Adding this
isdecrypted = SearchingString.substr((ID.size() + 4), 1);
```

will erase crypt information. but my purpose of asking this to learn alegorithm for further codes.

Comment: the isspace function is stateless. meaning there is no knowledge within isspace of previous calls to isspace returning true or false. so it is quite impossible for it to do what you're claiming it should do.

Comment: changing `std::remove_if` to `std::find_if` will presumably fix your problem. please provide a [mre]

Comment: @PatrickParker but remove_if didn't retuns last position before the removed character? (cppreference: "An iterator to the element that follows the last element not removed.")

Comment: But it did that: The last character not removed is the `y`, and it returned an iterator that follows that character.

Comment: @j6t Oh God! Thank You! my bad. so how can i save position of last removed character?

Comment: you are using isspace wrong: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace

Comment: What you currently do: remove certain characters, then truncate exccess room. What you really want: find position to truncate, then truncate there. See @AlanBirtles comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `std::remove_if()` you are removing ONLY whitespace characters, which is the opposite of what you want.

Since you know the starting position, use `std::find_if()` instead to find the ending position, and then `erase()` everything in between.

```cpp
std::string Mystr = "I Have A Nice Day";
size_t startPos = ...; // 9 for “Nice”
auto startIter = Mystr.begin() + startPos;
auto endIter = std::find_if(startIter, Mystr.end(),
    [](unsigned char ch){ return isspace(ch); }
);
if (endIter != Mystr.end()) {
    endIter = std::find_if(endIter+1, Mystr.end(),
        [](unsigned char ch){ return !isspace(ch); }
    );
}
Mystr.erase(startIter, endIter);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/zgKAMV)